# how to get date value from the @using (Html.BeginForm(

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, actionresult, html.beginform

In my razor view I have a simple form that's going to accept a date from user:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CancelByDate", "ClassExample", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "dateForm" }))
   {
      <input id="dateInput" type="date" width="10" class="date" />
      <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
   }
```

How to get this data in my CancelByDate Action?

I have tried few ways:

```
    public ActionResult CancelByDate(DateTime dateInput)  // <---- This value will be null
    {
        return View();  
    }

    public ActionResult CancelByDate(String dateInput)  // <---- This value will be null
    {
        return View();  
    }

    public ActionResult CancelByDate(object dateInput) // <---- This value will be some object, but there is no way to find out what is the underlying type even with GetType(); 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So I am wondering what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a name for date like below

```
<input id="dateInput" type="date" width="10" class="date" name="dateInput"/>
```

This name should match with the parameter name in your controller action.

If so the value will be automatically bound.